# How do I use Azure media service to apply watermark on video files which is of format mp4, OGG

Tags: video, download, watermark, azure-media-services, video-watermarking

Currently I am storing video files in Azure, I have requirement download these files with watermark. Watermark is in text format. Can I get help how to apply text watermark into video files? Technology using Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMS does not provide a text overlay feature - but we do have an image overlay feature.  If you can first format that text into an image, you can then re-encode the MP4 file using our Standard Encoder and the image overlay feature.

UPDATE:
this is the correct sample link for Javascript -
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_H264_OverlayImage

Comment: thanks for the info this is helpful. I wonder is it possible to rotate and scale up overlay image. I went through AMS Java SDK, it had information for position and opacity. Couldn't find info on rotate angle and scaling overlay image or watermark

Comment: No, there are not any image manipulation APIs. Only position and opacity are supported. 
You would need to provide the images in the right format for overlay.

Comment: @johndeu - the samples link you provided leads to a 404. Would you mind sharing an updated link?

Comment: Oh sorry, we have been moving some articles to code samples. 
Check this Javascript code sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_H264_OverlayImage